# Error setting up Apache 2.4 server on windows 10

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to setup apache2.4 on windows10 machine. I have downloaded the apache2.4 from apachelounge website, which I extracted and put in C drive. The lines I added in the httpd.conf file are-

```
LoadModule  PHP5_module "c:/PHP/PHP5apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir   "C:/PHP"
```

Now when the run the below command in command prompt with "run as admin" privilege,

```
c:\apache24\bin\httpd -S
```

I am getting the below error -

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 522 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `PHP5_module' in file C:/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll: No error
```

I have downloaded the PHP5.6 and extracted and put the same in C drive. Can anyone please me resolve this issue ?

Comment: What version of PHP are you trying to integrate with Apache

Comment: Try to change `LoadModule  PHP5_module ...` to `LoadModule  php5_module ...`, some time ago I have got a problem like yours and changing this line from upper case to lower case helped me

Comment: @RiggsFolly : My PHP version is 5.6.28

Comment: @SergeyLebedev : Thanks a looot, buddy! It worked :) could you please post it as answer so that I can accept that.

Comment: @SergeyLebedev : Now I got another problem. When I am typing localhost in chrome and press enter, I am expecting a proper page (with root directory folder structure). But it is giving - the site can't be reached. ANy idea of this one?

Comment: Find out where is your www-server document root folder - parameter DocumentRoot in in Apache config (file http.conf) and copy there PHP-files for your site. But as it seems that you are just starting to use Apache, you would better try something like XAMPP - Apache all-in-one distribution with already installed and set up PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `LoadModule PHP5_module ...` to `LoadModule php5_module ...`, some time ago I had this problem and changing this line from upper case to lower case helped me